# How to access user details in all pages in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

After login I want to access User details when ever I want (Particularly in navigation bar).
I did not use user model provided in django. I created my own model like this for authentication.
My database is stored in mysql on phpmyadmin(Xampp).

AdminUser Model

```
class adminUser(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mail=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    

    class Meta:
        db_table="admin_users"
```

admin_users.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        if username is not None and password is not None:
            user=adminUser.objects.get(username=username)
            hashed_password = user.password
            is_check = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'),hashed_password.encode('utf8'))
            print(is_check)
            if is_check==True:
                return redirect(reverse('faq_index'))
            else:
                return render(request,'AdminUsers/login.html')
    return render(request,'AdminUsers/login.html')
```

During the login User Details can be only access by login function but I want to access user details in all pages for navigation bar and also want to find out whether user is authenticated or not. As I am not using User Model defined in django so I can not use user.is_authenticated(). So How do I do this?

Comment: Go through the documentation on [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, inherit your user model from `AbstractBaseUser`. It gives you some features like `is_authenticated`, `set_password` and etc

Then define your custom user model as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py

After these, django treats to your custom user as its default user

**models.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Docs in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: If you go down this route, it may be easier to extend the `AbstractUser` model as shown [here](https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/django-custom-user-model-extending-abstractuser/)... It may be better to work with Django's built-in offerings than to start fresh...

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna recommend you take a step back, and extend the built-in User model instead of creating your own.

As mentioned by @Amin, you can extend the `AbstractBaseUser` class to create a custom User model, and override the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`.

However, you can easily add a `Profile` model that has a [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) with the built-in User model that does not require any overrides (which method is better escapes me at the moment, but I use the following method without issue):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
                                                                                                                                                                                 
UserModel = get_user_model()


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # add your desired fields here
    department=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then, in the same folder as contains your `models.py`, create a file called `signals.py`, and add the following code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_settings(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

This will trigger the creation of a new `Profile` object whenever a `User` object is created.

Then, add the following to the same folder's `apps.py` (Assuming the app's name is `users`... make it match the name of the app that contains your `Profile` model):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Now, after you run your migrations, you will be able to use the built-in `User` model, and add additional fields to it as desired in the `Profile` model.

The only downside is that it will require a little extra work if you want to modify the `User` model and the `Profile` model on the same page (ie. you won't just be able to specify the model name in an `UpdateView`).

I don't remember where I found this method. I believe it was adapted from [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) page on simpleisbetterthancomplex.com, but I'm not 100% sure.

At any rate, Django automatically creates a primary key `id` for you, so you probably don't need to manually define that in your model.