# Custom Authentication returning NULL everytime in django

Tags: python, django

I am beginner in django and I want to build authentication using custom user model.
I have asked question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039652/how-to-access-user-details-in-all-pages-in-django). I have been advised to inherit the User Model.

I created custom user model. As all the password are stored using bcrypt function so I created my own custom authentication. Now every time I login, I am getting None even if my password is correct. I want to know what I am missing?

models.py

```
class AdminUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password):
        if username is None or password is None:
            raise ValueError("Username and Password is Required")
        else:
            user = self.model(
                username = username,
                password = str(bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'),bcrypt.gensalt()),'utf-8')
            )
            user.save(using=self.db)
            return user



class AdminUsers(AbstractBaseUser):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mail=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # some more field
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mail']

    objects = AdminUserManager()
    class Meta:
        db_table="admin_users"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

backend.py

```
from .models import AdminUsers
import bcrypt

class CustomAuthentication(object):
    def authenticate(self,username,password):
        if username is not None and password is not None:
            user = AdminUsers.objects.get(username=username)
            hashed_password = user.password
            is_check = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'),hashed_password.encode('utf8'))
            if is_check == True:
                return user
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None
    
    def get_user(self,id):
        user = AdminUsers.objects.get(id=id)
        if user is not None:
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        if username is not None and password is not None:
            is_check = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            # user=AdminUsers.objects.get(username=username)
            # print(user.username,user.password)
            # hashed_password = user.password
            # is_check = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'),hashed_password.encode('utf8'))
            print(is_check)
            if is_check==True:
                return render(request,'Layouts/nav-side-bar.html',context={"User":is_check})
            else:
                return render(request,'AdminUsers/login.html')
    return render(request,'AdminUsers/login.html')
```

I have added `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and  `AUTH_USER_MODEL`  in settings.

*** Edit 1 ***

to check whether my CustomAuthentication is working or not, In authenticate function I commented some parts and return user without checking password. I am still getting None.
What I understand from this, my customauthentication is not being used for authentication.

```
def authenticate(self,username,password):
        if username is not None and password is not None:
            user = AdminUsers.objects.get(username=username)
            return user
            # hashed_password = user.password
            # is_check = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'),hashed_password.encode('utf8'))
            # if is_check == True:
            #     return user
            # else:
            #     return None
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made mistake while creating CustomAuthentication.
On creating `CustomAuthentication` I have to inherit the BaseBackend as given in [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/).
So backend.py should look like this. I hope it helps some one else facing same problem.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model
from .models import AdminUsers
import bcrypt
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend

class CustomAuthentication(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None):
        if username is not None and password is not None:
            user = AdminUsers.objects.get(username=username)
            hashed_password = user.password
            is_check = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'),hashed_password.encode('utf8'))
            if is_check == True:
                return user
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None
    
    def get_user(self,user_id):
        user = AdminUsers.objects.get(id=user_id)
        if user is not None:
            return user
        else:
            return None
```