# RuntimeError:doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm getting this error while i am using my own AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS

```
Model class tainfo.apps.users.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

my own backend:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
    import re
    from tainfo.apps.users.models import User
    
    
    def get_user_by_account(account):
        try:
            if re.match(r'1[3-9]\d{9}',account):
                user = User.objects.get(mobile=account)
            else:
                user = User.objects.get(username=account)
            return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
    
    class UsernameMobileAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
        def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None,**kwargs):
            user = get_user_by_account(username)
            if user and user.check_password(password) and user.is_active:
                return user
```

I put this in my devsettings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['users.utils.UsernameMobileAuthBackend',]
```

if i delete this from settings,then this error will gone,but i that case i won't be able to use my own auth backends.

any idea what i have done wrong?
thanks

updates:

my user model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, verbose_name='mobile',blank=True)
    email_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='emailisactive')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tb_users'
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

devsettings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'contents.apps.ContentsConfig',
    'verifications.apps.VerificationsConfig',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['users.utils.UsernameMobileAuthBackend',]
```

[dirs.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6x8K.png)

resolved:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
import re

from tainfo.apps.users.models import User
```

turns out it was the path that i used in utils..
apps's path is in my sys.path ,and i should use 'from users.models import User',like this :

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
import re

from users.models import User
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you show settings and User model?

Comment: yep...showed now ,thanks

Comment: Assuming taininfo is your project, Why did you put apps along with your settings ? or image is not full. If you want are trying to create customauthentication using custom User model, This may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069046/custom-authentication-returning-null-everytime-in-django/69069261#69069261

Comment: Can you please show the content of the class `VerificationsConfig`?